# How to detect the failure of a Lambda which is called by another Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've recently been dealing with a project which has a peculiar design - the server invokes an aws lambda which itself invokes another lambda - and the second lambda is failing.
 However, it seems the first lambda (the server-invoked one) is not receiving any error from the second one, so it just waits, and so does the server, until there is a timeout.

I was wondering if this is a common problem and if there is a "typical" solution, best-practices to consider, etc.

I don't think language is particularly important - I want to know if there's a simple, quick, direct way of dealing with the problem in the title without doing things like overhauling everything or setting global flags.

Comment: It means that the second Lambda is not written well and is not handling the error properly. The language runtime IS indeed important here as different runtimes have different ways of handling errors -- e.g. Node uses callbacks while the others can throw errors.

Comment: Sanity check ... presumably the 1st Lambda invokes the 2nd Lambda with RequestResponse invocation type (rather than Event)? How does the 2nd Lambda indicate an error (node.js function callback with an error object, or Java function throwing an exception, something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Step Functions? They're a great way of managing Lambda functions that need to happen sequentially or conditionally.

There's some pretty good debug features as well; you'll be able to see input and output data, and any errors.

https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/